# Issue getting background color to change

Tags: reactjs

I have a button that toggles a night mode that uses darker colors for components. The issue is once I turn on night mode it'll leave a white bar at the bottom / outlines of the components. So I'm assuming the background isn't changing correctly. The first function is setting the colors the second is changing the background I'm assuming the issue is with this second function or the index.html

```
function switchNightMode(){

  if(isNightMode){ 
    setIsNightMode(false);  
  }
  else{
    setIsNightMode(true);
  }

  //Setting colors and a duplicate for storing since this runs asynchronously 

  if(isNightMode){
    setNightMode(
      {
        background: "#413250", 
        bannerText: "#413250",
        listText: "#FFFFFF", 
        banner: "#FFFFFF",
        inputBackground: "#465C68"
      });   

      const currSession = {
        background: "#413250" ,
        bannerText: "#413250" ,
        listText: "#FFFFFF",
        banner: "#FFFFFF",
        inputBackground: "#465C68"
      };

      localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(currSession));
  }
  else{
    setNightMode({
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    });

    const currSession = {
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    };

    localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(currSession));
  }
}
```

Changes background:

```
React.useEffect(() => { 
    const savedBackground = localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = savedBackground.background; 
  }, [])
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,

      body{
        height:100%
      } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but I'd like to propose a slightly different approach to this problem. Move your CSS into a stylesheet and toggle a night-mode class on the html or body element and have all of your styles flow from there.

Here's a [working codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-kepler-dl7pr?file=/src/App.js:0-819) using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).

[image: day mode][image: night mode]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

// constant for className and local storage key
const NIGHT_MODE = "night-mode";

export default function App() {
  const html = document.querySelector("html");

  const toggleNightMode = () => {
    html.classList.toggle(NIGHT_MODE);

    // update localStorage value
    localStorage.setItem(NIGHT_MODE, html.classList.contains(NIGHT_MODE));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // restore night mode from local storage on mount
    const isNightMode = localStorage.getItem(NIGHT_MODE);
    if (isNightMode) {
      html.classList.add(NIGHT_MODE);
    }
  }, [html]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggleNightMode}>Toggle Night Mode</button>
      <h1 className="banner">Banner</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>A list item</li>
      </ul>
      <input value="An input" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
:root {
  --background: #ffffff;
  --bannerText: #ffffff;
  --listText: #000000;
  --banner: #55baf1;
  --inputBackground: #465c68;
}

.night-mode {
  --background: #413250;
  --bannertext: #bdb1c9;
  --listtext: #ffffff;
  --banner: #ffffff;
  --inputbackground: #465c68;
}

body {
  background: var(--background);
}

.banner {
  color: var(--bannertext);
}

ul {
  color: var(--listtext);
}

input {
  background: var(--inputbackground);
}
```

Comment: This is a clean solution but I've written too much code using my current method so it would just take too long to reformat. I'll use this as a reference for future apps though it's a better solution than what I'm doing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

My guess is since `setState` is asyncrhronous when your code gets to the second conditional check of `isNightMode` it hasn't been set to the new value yet.  You should only need use one conditional for all of your logic.

```
function switchNightMode(){

  if(isNightMode){
    setIsNightMode(false);

    setNightMode({
      background: "#413250", 
      bannerText: "#413250",
      listText: "#FFFFFF", 
      banner: "#FFFFFF",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    });   

    const currSession = {
      background: "#413250" ,
      bannerText: "#413250" ,
      listText: "#FFFFFF",
      banner: "#FFFFFF",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    };

      localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(currSession));
  } else {
    setIsNightMode(true);

    setNightMode({
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    });

    const currSession = {
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    };

    localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(currSession));
  }
}
```

I haven't tested your code, but I think this should work.

Also, I rewrote your code making it a bit more DRY

```
function switchNightMode(){
  const lightMode = {
      background: "#413250", 
      bannerText: "#413250",
      listText: "#FFFFFF", 
      banner: "#FFFFFF",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    }

  const darkMode = {
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    }

  let currentMode;

  if(isNightMode){
    setIsNightMode(false);
    currentMode = lightMode;
  } else {
    setIsNightMode(true);
    currentMode = darkMode;
  }

  setNightMode(currentMode);   

  localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(currentMode));
}
```

Comment: I like the simplified code it's definitely cleaner. The colors are changing fine but the white bar at the bottom is still visible. The document.body.style.backgroundColor isn't changing for some reason

Comment: Your useEffect hook is only firing on the initial component render, similar to how ```componentDidMount``` works with class based components. You need to pass in your ```nightMode``` state into the array as the second parameter so every time the value of ```nightMode``` changes it will trigger and you can do some logic (like updating DOM properties with new values) similar to how ```componentDidUpdate``` works with class based components.

Comment: I'm confused about one thing I'm using savedBackground.background which is pulling from currentMode. Therefore when currentMode changes shouldn't it update the useEffect hook as well. I'm not sure what change I should make to have it trigger

Comment: Your useEffect is only triggered on initial page node. You need to put nightMode into the array as the second parameter.